# How not to output an image to the browser?

Tags: php

My code:

```
ob_start();
imagejpeg($resource, NULL, 75);  break; // best quality
$resource = ob_get_contents();
ob_end_flush();
```

I use imagejpeg() only for output buffering, I dont need to output to browser. Any ideas?

Comment: clear ob before flushing.

Comment: Wouldn't it be easier to just let `imagejpeg()` save to a temporary file?

Answer (score 2):

Let's try to analyse what you did there:

```
// start output buffering
ob_start();
// output the image - since ob is on: buffer it
imagejpeg($resource, NULL, 75);
// this break could be a problem - if this is in a control structure, remove it
break;
// save the ob in $resouce
$resource = ob_get_contents();

// here is the image now in $resource AND in the output buffer since you didn't clean it (the ob)

// end ob and flush (= send the ob)
ob_end_flush();
```

So what you did wrong is, that you 1) didn't [clean](http://php.net/manual/en/function.ob-clean.php) the outputbuffer and/or 2) [flushed](http://php.net/manual/en/function.flush.php) the ob.

My recommendation would be to use `ob_get_clean` ([reference](http://php.net/manual/en/function.ob-get-clean.php)) (simple example):

```
$im = imagecreatetruecolor(120, 20);
ob_start();
imagejpeg($im);
$var = ob_get_clean();
```

Answer (score 0):

You break the process, if it is in a loop. So the OB will not be closed and the output is at the end of the parsing process. Also, you do not have to flush but to clean. Use:

```
ob_start();
imagejpeg($resource, NULL, 75); // best quality
$resource = ob_get_contents();
ob_end_clean();
break;
```

Or:

```
ob_start();
imagejpeg($resource, NULL, 75); // best quality
$resource = ob_get_contents();
ob_clean();
// Some other code
ob_end_flush(); // Output the rest
break;
```

Comment: See answer from @Marc to, `ob_get_clean()` is the short variant of `ob_get_contents(); ob_clean();`. But you have not end the OB then!